# Close a Session Upon Account Deletion

Tags: php, sql, security, session

Many websites I've created have user data stored in sessions for quick access. The problem is that if an Administrator chooses to delete or disable a user's account, as long as they have their session cookies they're still technically "logged in."

While there are a few workaround solutions, such as making a database check on the user before they make any changes or adding a database check into the logged in verification function, these are less efficient than I would like.

So my question is, is there a way to close a session for a user from another user based on data stored in said session, like a user ID? If not, when would it be considered insecure to use session data internally, without database verification?

I should note that this question is asked under the assumption that I will be using the built-in $_SESSION variable, not some sort of custom database implementation, since a database session would be fairly easy to track down.

I'm trying to avoid using a database since keeping session data on the local server is far more efficient than adding the latency of connecting to an external database every time I want to access session data.

Comment: You can try to use server code to give you access to what you need and allow the server to link between the session and the userid. Once you have that info, the server code should help you do what you need.

Comment: Have you looked at getting all the sesssions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248008/session-list-in-php

And how to kill a particular session:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730123/how-to-destroy-a-specific-php-session

Comment: The first link appears to assume use of the built-in SESSION, while the second one assumes a custom database-based session design. Perhaps using a database design is ideal. Is there any advantage to using a database session over just verifying it through the DB every time?

Comment: I like the idea of using the database session, as it allows you to rely on existing software, whereas the other method looks like it'd be more home cooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following achieve what you are looking for:

- Getting all the sesssions: [$_SESSION List in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248008/session-list-in-php)
- How to kill a particular session: [How to destroy a specific PHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730123/how-to-destroy-a-specific-php-session)

Comment: The first link is pretty much what I needed(how to search for a session ID based on data stored in the session), but the second link's answer is claiming it must be done using a custom database method. Another answer says something about using `session_id($sessionID);`, is this what you're referring to? Because I think that might work.. I'm just not certain how to go about obtaining the ID in question based on the first link.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `session_destroy`?

[Session Destory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Comment: "You seem to have misread the question. I am attempting to delete a session for which the user performing the deletion does not have the cookies for. In other words, allowing one user to delete another user's session."

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) at the end of the process, but furthermore:

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset [and] then the session cookie must be deleted.

<sub>As a side note: one 'good' thing about PHP documentation is you're absolutely, like, guaranteed a laugh.</sub>

Comment: You seem to have misread the question. I am attempting to delete a session for which the user performing the deletion does not have the cookies for. In other words, allowing one user to delete another user's session.

Comment: And this gives you such an answer.

Comment: If I'm the administrator and I delete the user "Bob", using session_destroy will delete MY session, not the session that the cookies on Bob's computer give access to. Unless I'm missing something, the documentation does not answer my question.

Comment: Does your session implementation use defaults? If so, a cookie is set per session, and you can't delete that cookie from another machine, ergo, your answer is "no" if you can read into the quote.

Comment: "I can't delete their cookies, of course, but I should be able to remove the session data on my server that their cookies link to."

Comment: Why _should_ you be able to? I don't know a single web framework that will give API access to individual sessions from another session in the session implementation.

Comment: To prevent users from being able to use their sessions after losing access to the website. Any database-implemented sessions could easily be searched through and have the offending session removed, it seems logical that it'd be possible with the standard implemention.
Doing so may be inefficient compared to doing it in a database-based session, but since user deletion is so uncommon it may be worth it.

This is a matter of efficiency, I've already listed a couple easy ways I could securely do it, but I'm hoping to use the highly-optimized built-in sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't destroy session on someone else his computer... . If you really want to do it, you should check on every page if the account is still available.. Or some other workaround.. .

Comment: I can't delete their cookies, of course, but I should be able to remove the session data on my server that their cookies link to.