# Access active sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

How can I get a list of all active PHP sessions on a server and access them from within one user's instance?

The motivating case is displaying a list of all currently active users on the site, where usernames are stored in each user's PHP session.

Note: I know that I can create my own state via a database (or even the filesystem), but I'm looking for a way to utilize the built-in PHP session mechanisms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping Through All a Server's Sessions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675913/looping-through-all-a-servers-sessions-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping Through All a Server's Sessions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675913/looping-through-all-a-servers-sessions-in-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seeing the responses, though it's possible, it doesn't mean you **should** do it. The format in which the sessions are stored is not documented and may change at any time (even between minor versions).

The *correct* way to do this is to implement your own [session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). It's not that hard, really.

Answer (score 8):

**Session List**

```
<?php
print_r(scandir(session_save_path()));
?>
```

**Check for a Specific Session**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo (file_exists(session_save_path().'/sess_'.session_id()) ? 1 : 0);
?>
```

**Time Session File Last Changed**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo filectime(session_save_path().'/sess_'.session_id());
?>
```

As has been done to death, already, it isn't best-practice to handle sessions this way but if it's needed, those will work without the need to check/modify the session storage path (useful if you switch to another server with a different configuration).

Answer (score 2):

The sessions are stored as files in your temporary session directory. You should be able to locate this in the php.ini (or using `phpinfo()` ).  Those are all the sessions. You should be able to check the file time to see if they are active within the last x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use sessions to do this, you would have to store the online users in a DB, and just set a timestamp or similar, the display all who are active with in 5 minutes, else delete their records.