# Is it possible to see active sessions using php?

Tags: php, wamp, lamp

I am developing a php application. Is it possible to get active sessions and session values on my server? 
And is it possible to end up a particular session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access active sessions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426844/access-active-sessions-in-php)

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675913/looping-through-all-a-servers-sessions-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want maximum flexibility with sessions you can save all your sessions in a database. Then it is very easy to get number of sessions, content of any session, kill them, etc...

http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database

As a bonus you will increase the security!

Comment: Yah... Will try this. But one a session get expired, database values will still remain as it is right?

Comment: There is a handler to a function that is called every once in a while in order to clean out (delete) old records in the session data store.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in PHP you cannot get the active sessions directly. But, you can create your own session handler ( http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php ) and manage the session files.