# Understanding PHP Session Entropy

Tags: php, session, entropy

In the `session` section of `php.ini` there is a directive called `session.entropy_length`.

I'm aware that it's used to make the generation of the Session ID "more random".

- How does it make the Session ID more random?
- What is the maximum length?
- What if it's length exceeds the bits of the `hash` in use?

Comment: 1. You probably shouldn't muck with it. 2. Answer is in the docs. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-length

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a replacement for reading the documentation.

Comment: @ceejayoz Document answers none of the questions. "It reads from a file" and then what? How is this applied (unanswered)? What is the maximum length (unanswered)? What if the bits exceed the hash (unanswered). Please, explain how the docs answer my question in any way.

Comment: First explain what problem you're solving by messing with the value. Quick Googling for "how are session IDs generated" results in a number of pieces of PHP docs, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937651/php-session-ids-how-are-they-generated.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for the php src. All clear now! I was searching for "session entropy" on Google and the results were disappointing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`session_id` is an hash  of the client IP address (32 bits), the current timestamp and microseconds (52 bits), and a value generated from the `php combined lcg()`, a Psuedo Random Number Generators (PRNG) function (64 bits). The entropy is 148 bits.  However, this number should not be considered as an absolute minimum value, as IP address and timestamp are well know from who creates the session.

When an undesirably low amount of entropy is available, it's possible to reconstructing the PRNG's *seed* from the session id. With the fact that PHP reuses the same entropy sources between different generators, this is even more easier.

The seed is used to generate other pseudorandom values, so if the attacker can obtain the seed value he can predict all the future output (including, but not only, `mt_rand()` and `rand`). That's not good.

`session.entropy_length` is the number of bytes which will be read from the entropy file, usually `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/arandom` ([from documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-length)).

If you provide a random source like `/dev/random`, then the entropy is greater, and the strength of the generated `session_id` is stronger.