# How to list all session in php

Tags: php

I have a simple shopping cart system , how to list all the registered session as shown below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['prod'][$_GET['id']])){
// How to list all $_SESSION['prod']['variable_here'] ?;
}
?>
```

Comment: print_r( $_SESSION['prod'] );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426844/access-active-sessions-in-php

Comment: Did you mean the session data? If yes, just using print_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i understand exactly what are you asking. 
Anyway, you may try this to list all your sessions.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['prod'][$_GET['id']]))
{
    // suppose that session is an array
    foreach ($_SESSION['prod'] as $session)
    {
        echo $session; // supposedly you want to echo it? 
    }
}
```

Is this what you want to achieve?
Regards
Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

As seesion is an array in php, you can php array functions for that.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION))
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['prod']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    echo '</pre>';
```