# how to check which users are signed in

Tags: codeigniter, session

i am beginner to code igniter. i am creating web service for android application that will have thousands of users. In admin panel i want to know which users are currently active. is it possible using sessions?

```
$newdata = array(
                            'phone'  => $phone,
                            'pass'     => $pass,
                            'logged_in' => TRUE
                    );
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

storing user data in session like this but don't know how to check later

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426844/access-active-sessions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track online users you can add one flag(field) like "is_loggedin".
When any user login update this value to 1
When any user logout date this flag to 0

So you can check any time in database that user's with flag 1 are online.