# unset a session by value?

Tags: php, session

is it possible to unset session by it's value ?

i have a chat application and it identifies user/pears using session called username , i want to be able to unset each session from admin panel .

i have user session value in admin and i can send it to the chat app to unset that specific user by ajax .

```
$kick_out = $_post['username'];
if($_session['username'] == $kick_out )
unset( $_session['username']  );
```

but the thing is i don't want to unset all the  `$_session['username']`  , just the one that has `$kick_out value`

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675913/looping-through-all-a-servers-sessions-in-php + the read the first comment!

Answer (score 0):

Then make the condition:

```
if{$_session['username'] == $kick_out} unset( $_session['username']);
```

Comment: i dont want to unset all username sessions , this unsets all of them

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are assigning the kickout value , you are not making a comparison against it.
if you have a $_SESSIONS["username"] can you var dump it so we get a glue what is it? object?array?multidimensional array?string?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify other users' sessions. If you want to forcefully logout someone you need to store a flag in your database which is checked on every request from a logged-in user.

Comment: there is no logging in and no database(well at least for users ) .  when user opens the page i ask for a nickname and set the session .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unset someones session, it's impossible.You can store session id to database and when you want to kick someone, set session id empty and every time check if $_SESSION at user is same as from database where username equal to logged in username..